# Hibernate 4.3 + Tomcat 7 Unable to lookup JNDI name

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I have a trouble upgrading to Hibrernate 4.3.x from 4.2.7. I got this exception:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/data] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:114)
... 82 more
```

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.29 (tried 7.0.47 as well) and JDK 7 (v25). There is no problem with Hibernate 4.2.7.

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="data" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/data</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

But I don't think the problem is here. I did a little bit of debug research and found out the following:

`JndiServiceImpl#locate(String jndiName)` creates an initial context which differs.

4.3.0 - `org.apache.naming.NamingContext`

4.2.7 - `org.apache.naming.SelectorContext`

Except for this, I couldn't find any more differences.

I found some similar topics for this issue, but none of help. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you define any datasource in server.xml?

Comment: No, I did not. Should I? I have never defined any DS in server.xml.

Comment: Someone posted a bug report here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8818

Comment: Hey everybody, according the https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8818 the bug is resolved in 5.0.0, 4.3.6. Haven't tried myself yet.

Comment: @benjamin.d You better define it in `<project>/META-INF/context.xml` and override it after deployment in `apache-tomcat-7.0.28\conf\Catalina\localhost\<project>.xml` to keep the `server.xml` clean. otherwise you must copy the database-configuration in the `server.xml` for every hostname in `<Host name="xxx">`

Answer (score 0):

Yea, its actually buggy, because they took different focus on how a `session-factory` works and when the factory is asked for a connection.

So you need to resolve it behind the `session-factory` to use it when the `session-factory` requests a fresh connection.

Try to solve the DataSource in jndi in sole respolsibility of hibernate, via the old-scool `hibernate.cfg.xml` like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="data">
        <property name="connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/data</property>
    ...
```

And resolve the config via `persistence.xml` like this:

```
<persistence version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="data">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
```

Maybe your `hbm2ddl` must move to `hibernate.cfg.xml` too then.

Have fun.