# JNDI look up fails on Hibernate 4.3.5 final - javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [xxx] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [xxx]

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jndi, jpa-2.1

I'm trying to upgrade Hibernate from 4.2.7 final to [4.3.5](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/) final running on Tomcat 8.0.5 using Spring 4.0.0 GA and JSF 2.2.6.

The following libraries are added to the classpath.

- antlr-2.7.7.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
- javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
- jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
- jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
- jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
- **hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.5.Final.jar**

And for generating a static metamodel (processor).

- hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.5.Final.jar

After upgrading, the following exception is thrown.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/social_networking]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5159)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload(HostConfig.java:1370)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1348)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1532)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1143)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1371)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1347)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/social_networking]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/social_networking] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:114)
    ... 47 more
```

The persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="SocialNetworkingPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/social_networking</non-jta-data-source>

    <!-- A list of persistent entities -->

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/social_networking"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The application-context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="admin.mangedbean converter validator user.bean client.managedbean" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory" >
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
              <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false"/>
            </map>
        </property>

        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/social_networking"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="view">
                    <bean class="scope.ViewScope" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- A list of registered beans -->

</beans>
```

The context.xml file under `META-INF`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/SocialNetworking">
    <Resource name="jdbc/social_networking" 
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100"
              maxIdle="30"
              maxWait="10000"
              username="root"
              password="password"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/social_networking"/>
</Context>
```

In web.xml, a resource reference is added as follows.

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/social_networking</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

I already tried changing the name from `java:comp/env/jdbc/social_networking` to `java:/comp/env/jdbc/social_networking` but that did not make a difference either.

Why does it fail to locate a resource using a JNDI on the latest Hibernate release?

---

**EDIT :**

I have chosen a temporary way as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16431382/1391249) question/accepted answer, not using a JNDI until the potential [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8818) is fixed in a future release.

Comment: Can you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911439/refering-tomcat-jndi-datasource-in-persistence-xml and see if this works?

Comment: Peeped through the link but I found nothing wrong in the given configurations. So, no clue. It fails only on the latest Hibernate version. Difficult to envision the actual cause of the exception.

Comment: This appears to be an unresolved [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8818). Fixed version(s) are none.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20135117/1391249) is a very similar question still unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8818) that causes a JNDI look up to fail has been fixed as of [Hibernate 4.3.6 final](http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/) (and upcoming releases).

In this particular case, in the existing code snippets in the question however, `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect` in the `persistence.xml` file needs to be replaced by `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` or the following exception is thrown (I'm using MySQL 5.6.11 with `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18`).

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

Since Hibernate 4 does a fantastic job of determining which dialect to use based on the JDBC driver provided, it also works, even though this dialect itself is removed in its entirely from `persistence.xml` but that depends...